# Why present view with servlet if we can do it with jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, servlets

It seems that both can represent a view, that is if you request a `servlet` it will show you an html page, and so the same if you request a `jsp` file, just the way they are implemented are different.

Now I know that `servlet` are more than, that. They control requests and so on, but still after reading so many days, still don't know how to use them in harmony together.

If i need some logic, do I put it in a `servlet`, and then what? How do I present my data, from the `servlet` or from a `jsp` file located in the same folder?

In other words, do I even need `jsp` files when I use `servlet`, and if yeas why???

Comment: Try to write some HTML page in Servlets, you will get an idea. Certainly, you don't want to wired up in those HTML in `out.println` statement, that's so difficult, and unreadable to do.

Comment: @Rohit Jain So you would also write the logic of your program in the `jsp` file, and how about if you wanted to communicate with an `EJB` ?

Comment: I didn't say, I would write business logic in my JSP. Servlet's job is of a controller. Writing View code in Servlets is very complex, and also it doesn't complies to MVC pattern.

Comment: but they seem competing technologies, they dont seem to be working together?  For example writing the business logic in a servlet and the view in the jsp ?

Comment: I suggest you to go through some good MVC tutorial, or a good book. You will understand how Servlets and JSP interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that both can represent a view, ...

JSP was introduced because it's much easier to invoke Java to render parts that are dynamic in an otherwise static HTML template rather than trying to print out the whole page in Java through servlets (too many *println()*, escaping quotes etc. it's a mess). So, JSP is better suited for rendering views.

***MVC** is all about separation of concerns: request handling and routing, business logic and application data, and the views with all the presentation logic*.

JSPs later enhanced with **EL** *(Expression Language)*, **JSTL** *(Java Standard Tag Lbrary)* and other such *tag libraries* that encapsulate the presentation logic are better suited to support the **View** layer.

**Model** represents your application data and all the business rules that you apply on them. They're implemented as *POJOs* (plain old Java objects i.e. not extending or implementing platform specific classes or interfaces) .

Servlets and Filters with their request dispatching capabilities and inherently existing in the Java environment are better suited as **Controllers** to interact with the Application Server, the Model and the View. They facilitate all the routing and the flow of data between the three layers.

> If i need some logic, do I put it in a servlet, and then what?

Your business logic neither goes in Servlets nor JSPs. That goes into your business classes *(POJOs)* insulated as much as possible from the type of application platform (which is *J2EE* here).

A simple request to demonstrate its use would be to ask you to port your application into *.Net*. A-ha! Suddenly, writing all that business logic inside your Servlets/JSPs, that cannot be easily reused now, doesn't feel like such a good idea.

So, ideally, your servlets would intercept the client requests and invoke some business class to fulfill it. This may return some data (like results from a SQL query) wrapped as a ***domain data*** object (also referred to as *data value* or *data transfer* objects).

> How do I present my data, from the servlet or from a jsp file located in the same folder?

Before redirecting to an appropriate *View*, the *Controller* servlet would **push** the domain object into some **scope** (could be *request*, *session* or *application* depending on the requirements) or a sophisticated data store available with an MVC framework (like the *ValueStack* in Struts 2).

The *View*, which is your JSP, would then **pull** the domain object from one of these scopes or *ValueStack* and render its required properties for display through EL with JSTL tags or OGNL expressions with tag libraries provided by the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

It is of good style to separate logic from presentation. (1) You can easily change the logic not touching the presentation and vice versa. (2) You can use a right tool for each task. Pure Java in servlet's code is good for implementing logic. Templating engine, including JSP, is good for presentation, where your work is largely in HTML with some points where you're inserting data from the application.

You can read about Spring as an example how to use JSP in the best way.

Comment: From reading it seems, that both do the same thing but in a different way. Can they both also work together, for example using servelt, only for java code, and using jsp, to present that logic to the user?

Comment: Yes, for sure. You can call JSP engine from a servlet, if you want.

Comment: @lamed , when you separate logic from presentation, it is called "making a template". When you separate business logic from presentation logic, it can be called "making a view". View in MVC is **not a template**.